Thingsboard - Timeseries widgets to show the data, however extrapolated per hour
We are receiving data from a PLC device multiple times per minute on Thingsboard.
To keep things easy lets say this device is a light switch (LS). It's an increasing integer value.
The widget is linked to the dashboards time window. Data aggregation ist set to Average and Grouping interval to 2 minutes.
Since this is an every increasing value and we are interested in the difference to the last value we use the function of the LS data key:
  if (!value) {
      return 0;
  }
  if (!prevOrigValue) {
      return null;
  }
  return (value - prevOrigValue);

Now to the actual issue. We are interested in the theoretical data per hour. From the currecnt data, how often would the LS theoretically be pushed per hour?
Therefore we'd multiply the returned value from the funtion by 30 (because 2 minuts (Grouping interval) times 30 equals to an hour). Like this:
  if (!value) {
      return 0;
  }
  if (!prevOrigValue) {
      return null;
  }
  return (value - prevOrigValue) *30;

However, if a user would change the dashboards Grouping interval, the values would be wrong. And it is desired to to so.
Is there a way to read the current dashboards Grouping interval from the function above to set the multiplier correctly?
e.G.: Grouping interval 5 would result in a multiplier of 12 (5*12 = 1 hour)
Or is this a foolish approach and there is a better/propper way to reach the desired outcome?
We wish to see theoretical values per hour based on current data.
Thank you.

That was probaply not explained very well.
In way simpler terms:
Lets say the device we're getting data from is a CAR and the data is the distance the car has traveled.
I'd like to display the speed (km/h resp. miles/h).
Example:
Data point:
timestamp: 20240101_0800
value: CAR1.distance  = 5km


Data point:
timestamp: 20240101_0830
value: CAR1.distance  = 55km`

To be displayed: 100km/h
How?
duration = 30 minutes (0800 to 0830)
distance = 50 km (5 to 55)
km per hour = distance / duration (in hours)

But how would I accomplish that in a Thingsboard timeseries widget?
Thank you
